# How to show Angular Material Stepper's matStepperNext button as enabled/disabled?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

In an Angular 11 project I have an [Angular Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/) control. My first step contains a form much like this:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="step.formGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
            <label for="code">Enter code</label>
            <input name="code" formControlName="code" required />
            <button matStepperNext>Continue</button>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <!-- step 2 -->
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I would like to show the `<button>` that's decorated with `matStepperNext` as disabled when the form has errors and enabled when it doesn't using CSS classes. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button matStepperNext [ngClass]="{'disabled': formGroup.get('code').hasError(error)}">Continue</button>
```

CSS of the button:

```
button.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I would still suggest to handle it using `disabled` attribute on the button.

Comment: thank you. How can I use the button's `disabled` attribute inside the `[ngClass] ` attribute?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add `disabled` attribute inside `[ngClass]`. The other solution I was talking about was something like this `<button matStepperNext [disabled]="formGroup.get('code').hasError(error)">Continue</button>`

Comment: the `<button>` is disabled by the stepper itself. I don't even see the `disabled` attribute on it when that happens. I'm wondering how I can set the `ngClass` based on whether the button is enabled or disabled.